# compare complexity of matrix transpose

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Given 2 matrices: $X(rows=m,cols=n)$ and $Y(rows=m,cols=1)$, which of the following operations is computationally easy, i.e., easy on the machine?

$$X^{T} \times Y \\
or \\
(Y^{T} \times X)^{T} $$

Comment: For practical computations with the standard matrix multiply algorithm, it will depend on whether the matrices are stored in [row-major or column-major format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). One would chose the one that makes the algorithm access sequential elements in memory, rather than striding across jumps in memory. From a theoretical computer science perspective, the [fastest algorithm for multiplying matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) is not known - presumably the theoretical answer to this question would depend on the algorithm.

Comment: The symbol $X$ appears twice in your question, please fix this. Is the second matrix $m \times 1$ or $m \times \ell$?

Comment: @HansEngler - done. thanks for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 1):

The operational count (number of multiplications and additions) is the same for each approach.

If your software uses column-major order (e.g. Fortran, Matlab, R), then the computation of $Y^TX$ will be easier - but the transposition in memory to get $(Y^TX)^T$ from $Y^TX$ may be expensive.

If you are using row-major order (C/C++/C#, Mathematica, Python), the first approach will be easier and not require an additional transposition.